# Matrix factorization how to initialize weights and biases?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, matrix-factorisation, weight-initialization

I have a matrix factorization and I'm wondering how I should initialize its weights and biases.

When getting prediction (recommendation), after computing a dot product and adding bias I want to use sigmoid function on that to get value from 0 to 1.

But when introducing a sigmoid here I also introduce a possibile vanishing/exploding gradient problem. For that I think that weights can be initialized with xavier function. But what aboud biases? Should I just use uniform distribution from (-0.01, 0.01) for example?

Answer (score 1):

For matrix factorization I usually see it being initialized by a uniform distribution from [0, 1) like in [this (pytorch)](https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-implementation-of-matrix-factorization-391bfc003e43) or a truncated normal with mean=0.0 and std=1.0 as in [this (tensorflow)](http://hameddaily.blogspot.com/2016/12/simple-matrix-factorization-with.html).